# How to get just last word for a variable in a PHP "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" request?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, uri

I'm using WAMP and the root folder of my page is: `http://localhost/projects/bp/`

In a Worpress application and I want to give unique id's to the `body` tag of every Page. So I did the following:

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $page = str_replace("/","",$page);
    $page = str_replace(".php","",$page);
    $page = str_replace("?s=","",$page);
    $page = $page ? $page : 'default'
?>

<body id="<?php echo $page ?>">
```

When I clicked the `About`page the URL change to the following: `http://localhost/projects/bp/about` and `$page` showed the following value:`projectsbpabout`

What can I do so that $page just show the last word of the URL. In this case, `about`, I don't want the `projectsbp` part)?

Do I have to change something in the Wordpress routing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use PHP's built-in path parsing functions to do this.

Use [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/parse_url) to cut off the query and get only the path part:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

(parse_url is used to parse full URLs but should work fine for this. The second parameter is available since PHP 5.1.2.)

Then use [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to extract the file name:

```
$pagename = basename($path, ".php");  // Will remove `.php` suffix
```

**Additional thougths**

Depending on how your site is structured, this method will not necessarily make for unique IDs. What if `about` is a sub-page in `/bp` and `/bc`? (If that is possible in Wordpress.) You would have two different pages with the same ID. In that case, you may want to use the full path as an identifier, converting slashes into underlines:

```
<body id="projects_bp_about">
```

also from own experience, I recommend using classes for this to avoid ID collisions if a page is named like an already existing elements on the page!

```
<body class="projects_bp_about">
```

Comment: @Pekka Thanks that worked! (Good to always see you around). One more thing, how can I add a default to $pagename, say home (like, if $pagename is something else, body = home ?

Comment: @janoChen `$base = basename($path, ".php"); $pagename = ($base != "" ? $base : "home");`

Comment: @Pekka sorry that didn't work because when the page is in the root folder (http://localhost/projects/bp/) $pagename = bp not sure why.

Comment: @jano what does `basename()` return in that case? I think it should return `bp`: If it does, replace `$base != ""` by `$base != "bp"`.

Answer (score 2):

As `/` is your separator, first create an array of all the loose parts:
`$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`
Now you just want the last element:
`$last_part = end($parts);` 
of course this can also be done in one go:

`$last_part = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Comment: sorry I tried that but it didn't work. Should I delete the previous code and replace it by yours?

Comment: Don’t forget the other higher level separator as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the requested URI path *and* query (see also Pekka’s answer).

Answer (score 0):

to get only the last bit you can use

```
$page = array_pop(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

explode the string by '/' and get the last piece.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using str_replace you can use..

$pageArr = explode("/",$page);

it will give you array with three values you can capture the last one as about